# How do I change the properties of database item through Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, frameworks, entity

I would like to save the changes made to an object's properties that is saved in the DB through Entity Framework so that the id-s do not change only the properties.
I tried removing it and adding it again but I get the following error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.'
I tried to set the Entity's state to modified but I get an error saying the id-s conflict with another db item (the one I want to modify, I want it to stay the same).
I have not seen any modification done before so I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the object from the database context.
2. Modify the object properties.
3. Save changes in the database context (e.g. `_yourContext.SaveChanges()`).

Comment: Thank you, it almost works. I have listbox with the entities, if I click on the Entity I lists the properties for me. As long as I don't close the program it lists the modified property. But as soon as I relaunch the program I lists the original. How can this happen?